2015 Honda Odyssey. How to charge my APU only when the car battery is not being charged?
I have a 2015 Honda Odyssey and an APU (battery) that I want to charge at 400W (on the highway). To avoid overloading the alternator, I want to charge my APU only when the car battery is not being charged. How can I prevent overloading the alternator to charge my battery?

How will you be limiting the charging to 400W instead of the total available capacity of the alternator? You can click EDIT below your question to add additional info.

You don't have to worry about overloading your alternator. It's self-limited.
Alternators are inherently limited by their design to produce up to but not more than their rated amps. As long as the alternator is clean (not coated or clogged with dust or grease), is getting adequate air flow, and is spinning at adequate RPM, it can produce its rated amps as long as needed. You said "on the highway" so RPM will be adequate.
If a load greater than the alternator's rated amps is attached, the system voltage will start to drop, and as soon as voltage drops to the starting battery's standing voltage, the battery will supply any current shortfall.
Think about it -- say you've just started the car in a snowstorm and it's idling. You turn on the headlights, wipers, seat heaters, defroster on max, rear window defogger and you adjust your seat. That's way more amps than the alternator can possibly produce at idle. An overload? No. The alternator does what it can and the battery supplies the rest until you start driving at higher RPM. No problem.
So attach your APU. Best to power it from a fuse that has power only when the ignition is on so it doesn't drain the battery when the engine is off.
